# OpenSSL invalid revocation date / update CRL?

Tags: openssl, certificate, self-signed-certificate, crl, revoked

I have an `index.txt` file where I changed the value of a certificate - whose certificate file I do not have - from `V` to `R` to revoke it.

The index.txt looks as follows exemplarily:

```
V    220303095424Z     123456      unknown /bla 
R    220303104529Z     123457      unknown /bla ... CN=test1234
```

If I want to create a new certificate test1234, it says

```
invalid revocation date
 in entry 2
```

Question: What to do? Do I have to update the CRL.pem? If yes, how to that via OpenSSL?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A revocation list can only be created, if a *revocation time* is specified in index.txt. You failed to specify that date.

Any line holding a revoked certificate needs to have an additional column with the revocation date, after the expiration date. Change the last line of your file to something like

```
R    220303104529Z   220305000000Z  123457      unknown /bla ... CN=test1234
```

and you should be good.